# How do I get a C program to work as a Windows Application Form?

Tags: c, sockets, windows

Hi I am a beginner in C programming and I have made a C program that automatically logins into a website using socket programming, particularly made for UNIX systems. I am now interested in bringing this program into "life" in windows application form, so that it would be much easier to use. But I am clueless on where to start because I have never programmed in Windows before. A simple guide to what steps I should take would be very much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself a Windows installation and install an express version of the C++ IDE.  In there you can create Win32 API applications from which you could start to build your app.  You will need to use the Win32 API to build your form.  This API is fairly well documented on the internet.  [Here](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) is a website with some tutorials on it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I mean [VC++ Express 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express)

Comment: I had no idea it had been proclaimed **the** C++ IDE.

Comment: It isn't **the** IDE per se, just the one that I use.  I guess my wording was bad. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library for that. For example i like `Qt` but it tends to be large but it is multiplatform. You could also use `Win32++` for that. But it requires some reading since it is very close to the windows api (WinAPI).

Just for completeness there is also ATL, WTL, MFC, GTK (multiplatform), wxWidgets and some others i don't recall.